# struct array de caracteres

Tags: array, c++, struct

Estou tendo que relembrar programação em c++ para ensinar uma turma iniciante em lógica de programação. Assunto este que não vejo há anos.

Uma `struct` foi declarada porém ao entrar com uma cadeia de caracteres, a stream salta para a próxima linha. Procurei tópicos relacionados por aqui não encontrei nada relacionado.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Agenda{
    char nome[50];
    int cod;
};

int main()
{
    Agenda a[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout << "Nome: ";
        cin.get(a[i].nome, 50);
        cout << "Cód: ";
        cin >> a[i].cod;

    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout << a[i].nome << "\t" << a[i].cod << "\n";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Imagem da execução

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja vou agradecendo daqui

Comment: Usando cin.getline(a[i].nome, 50); consegui escrever um segundo nome, mas acaba por acontecer o mesmo.. espero ter ajudado com ideias

Comment: Eis o meu problema. Usando apensa o objeto cin, passando apenas uma cadeia de caracteres sem espaços, consigo. De outra forma, não

Answer (score 4):

O problema está no `cin.get` e na forma como ele funciona. Na verdade misturar formas de leituras diferentes:

1. `cin >>`
2. `cin.get`

Regra geral cria complicações, pois existem cenários em que não se comportam de igual forma.

Vou começar por citar a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) sobre o `cin.get` num pormenor importante:

> The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream

Em tradução livre:

> O delimitador não é extraido da sequência da entrada se for encontrado, e permanece na mesma ficando como o próximo caratere a ser extraido.

Então acontece que quando lê o primeiro codigo com `cin >> a[i].cod` o `\n` fica na entrada, e de seguida quando vai com o `cin.get` não lê nada porque o `\n` é o primeiro caratere e é logo um delimitador. E o `cin.get` também não o retira da entrada criando um ciclo vicioso até ao fim.

Após perceber o problema tem algumas soluções.

### `cin.ignore`

o [`cin.ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) permite lhe descartar carateres da entrada, podendo até especificar quantos quer descartar. No seu caso precisa apenas de descartar um que corresponde ao `\n`, que tem de ser feito no sitio certo:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout << "Nome: ";
    cin.get(a[i].nome, 50);
    cout << "Cód: ";
    cin >> a[i].cod;
    cin.ignore(); // <-- consumir a quebra de linha que ficou aqui
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/8kvOaa)

### Ler tudo com `>>`

Se fizer todas as leituras da mesma forma regra geral funciona certo, pois todos consomem as quebras no mesmo sitio.

**É importante mencionar que numa leitura de `string` isto pode ser limitativo se quiser que a string possa ter espaços**, pois esta leitura apenas lê até ao espaço, ou seja, apenas uma palavra.

Se não for o caso funciona perfeitamente, veja o exemplo:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout << "Nome: ";
    cin >> a[i].nome; // agora com >>
    cout << "Cód: ";
    cin >> a[i].cod;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/L0KdTC)

### Usando `std::string`

Em C++ tem melhor forma para armazenar strings, que é utilizar `std::string` e que lhe simplifica a vida, evitando ter de controlar terminadores de strings, e outros pormenores.

É interessante mencionar isto pois acabou cometendo um erro comum precisamente neste ponto, pois a leitura do `nome` coloca-lhe um terminador adicional na string, logo tem de ler `49` carateres e não `50` para evitar que saia fora do espaço alocado.

Se trocar o campo da estrutura para `std::string` pode fazer a leitura com [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) e tudo fica mais simples:

```
//...    
struct Agenda{
    string nome; // agora string
    int cod;
};

int main(){
    Agenda a[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout << "Nome: ";
        getline(cin, a[i].nome); //leitura com getline
        cout << "Cód: ";
        cin >> a[i].cod;
        cin.ignore(); //ignore na mesma
    }

    //...
```

[Veja também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/XkV4Os)